# Selenium webdriver: Element is not clickable at point (707, 455)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When i get error like this:

```
Element is not clickable at point (707, 455)
```

How could I exactly determine where exactly on the page was click performed?

Like:

[image]

Comment: selenium code? html code?

Comment: yes, it is selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here click is performed, Please see the full Exception. There should be exception like **Click is receive by other element {html-tag-of-the-received-element}**. And this element is overlap your element(xpath) partially or fully.
If that element(xpath) is completely overlapped, you cant able to click until overlap element disappears. Otherwise if is partially overlapped, then use *clickWithCoordinates* method to click.